# Is there a way to return a value in the Response?

Tags: asp.net

The problem is I redirect to a sub page from the main page by passing a few values in Request.
I need to get back the value I got from manipulating values I sent in request and I don't need to store value in Session.

Comment: [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) is your friend.

Comment: Thanx Oded for ur reply but if I am right Viewstate is maintained at page level. view state of one page is not visible to another page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`PreviousPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) property, depending on how you got to the new page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can do:

- Page.Request["ID_Of_Control_You_Are_Interested_In"]  will get you a value that you need.
- If you Server.Transfer to the page you can call Context.Handler, cast it to the page you come from and traverse the controls collection to get your value.... (similar to PreviousPage property)

You can also inspect the Query string parameters sent in the request too:

- Page.Request.QueryString("Param_To_Inspect")

Comment: Dat I kno how to pass parameters in Request but how to get value from response

Comment: You might like to override the render method and edit the response by modifying the HttpTextWriter?  You could also implement a HttpModule and directly edit the response in the methods it utilises.

Answer (score 0):

you can return your values as JSON as the response and then using a jquery to get the data

Answer (score 0):

You have three options: Query String Parameters, Cookies and Session State

**Query String Parameters**: http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/11/using-the-querystringparameter/

This is a good way to pass data between pages. It's the most commonly used and is limited to the max length of the url.

**Cookies** : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx
This is a good method. It also has a size limitation. The advantage of cookies is you can persist data that can span visits to your site.

**Session State** : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx
This an ok method, I'd use the two methods above before I would use session state. In my experience you can get into trouble very fast with Session state.

*To answer your question:* You can take the value from the request and load it into a TextBox. Then on the web page, the user edits the value and clicks a save button, which posts the changed value back to the server.

Or you could use javascript to post the value back to the server.